# Extend bluebird promise resolved value using bluebird .return() method

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to extend promise resolved value by using bluebird's [`.return()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/return.html) method.

Currently I'm using the following code:

```
doSomethingAsync()              // assume resolved value is {a: 0}
    .return({b: 1})
    .then(console.log);         // prints {b: 1}
```

I would like to extend the `result` object ({b: 1}) with `doSomethingAsync` resolved value, in this case `{a: 0}`, so I could write something like:

```
var extend = require('extend');

doSomethingAsync()                          // assume resolved value is {a: 0}
    .return(extend(resolvedValue , {b: 1}))
    .then(console.log);                     // should print {a: 0, b: 1}
```

Is it possible to access `doSomethingAsync()` resolved value (in that case `{a: 0}`) from within the `.return()` parameter?

Comment: This is now how `.return` should be used. The reference page mentions that value used `.return` should be bound at the time of calling `.return`. You should just a normal `.then` and have the extend method return the extended object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment this is not how `.return` should be used. Simply use something like this instead:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const _ = require('lodash');

Promise.resolve({a: 1}).then(obj => _.extend(obj, {b: 2})).then(console.log);
```

Prints: `{ a: 1, b: 2 }`